# Unicast UDP packet miss

Tags: c, udp

Unicast(one to one) UDP communication, each time the packet received is not same; if I am sending 1000 packets within interval of 500ms I get 9 packets missed. I am working on windows platform VCC 6.0; using sendto system call to send the Ethernet packet. In the host side I miss the packets by checksum error or header error.

Please let me know if you need more details. My agenda is that I should not miss any packets in target side.
Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

```
{
    //Initialize local variables 
    MAINAPP(pAppPtr);
    int iResult = 0;
    int sRetVal = 0;
    static char cTransmitBuffer[1024];
    unsigned long ulTxPacketLength =0;
    int in_usTimeOut = 0;
    unsigned short usTimeout = 0;

    S_QJB_POWER_CNTRL S_Out_QJB_Power_Cntrl = {0};

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_ucHeader[0] = QJB_TCP_HEADER_BYTE1;

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_ucHeader[1] = QJB_TCP_HEADER_BYTE2;

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_usCmdID = QJB_ETH_POWER_ON;

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_usCmdResults = 0;

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_usDataSize = sizeof(S_QJB_POWER_CNTRL);

    //Fill the controls & delay
    sRetVal = PowerCntrlStructFill(&pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.U_Tcp_Msg.S_QJB_PowerCntrl,&usTimeout);

    if(sRetVal)
    {
        return sRetVal;
    }

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_usReserved = 0;

    pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.m_usChecksum = 0;
    //Perform Endian Swap
    pAppPtr->objEndianConv.EndianSwap(&pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg.U_Tcp_Msg.S_QJB_PowerCntrl, &S_Out_QJB_Power_Cntrl);

    //Frame the transmission packet 
    QJB_Frame_TXBuffer(cTransmitBuffer, &(pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Tx_Msg), &ulTxPacketLength,(void *)&S_Out_QJB_Power_Cntrl);

    //Send the data to the target
    iResult = sendto(pAppPtr->sktConnectSocket,cTransmitBuffer,ulTxPacketLength,0,(struct sockaddr *)&pAppPtr->g_dest_sin, sizeof(pAppPtr->g_dest_sin));
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
       return QJB_TARGET_DISCONNECTED;
    }

    memset(&pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Rx_Msg,0,sizeof(S_QJB_ETHERNET_PKT));// 1336
    //Send the Command and obtain the response
    sRetVal = QJB_ETHResRev(pAppPtr->sktConnectSocket,&pAppPtr->S_Tcp_Handle.Tcp_Rx_Msg,3);
    return sRetVal;
}
```

Sathishkumar.

Comment: UDP makes no delivery guarantees, so some packets can get lost. If you need all packets to be delivered, use TCP. And please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since UDP makes no guarantees about delivery, the network stack can drop your sent packets at any time for any reason. It is worth noting there is no order gurantee of the orders the packets will arrive in as well.

If ordering and delivery is prime to your application, which I think it is, consider switching to TCP.

Comment: I am working in a project where i should not use TCP; can UDPlite can be implemented in msdn if we can implement how to implement??

Comment: UDP-lite will still not guarantee packet delivery, rather it just allows the application to process 'damaged' data. However if you still wish to go ahead with it, Linux has built in support added kernel > 2.6.20. For windows there is a WULL library, I don't think its free. You can get an idea of its implementation here: https://www.irisa.fr/temics/softwares/WULLUserGuide.pdf